# How can I check if user input is a directory path in php command line

Tags: php, cmd, stdin

I am using php to write a small cmd program, I want to check if user input in php command line is valid directory  path or not in order to apply my functions on that directory .

This is a piece of code I write:

```
  $stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');


  do{
  echo "\nplease enter valid directory : ";
  $response = fgets($stdin);
  echo "\n".$response;

   if(is_dir($response)){
     echo "directory";
     break;
    }else{
     echo "Not directory";
   }
  } while(1);
```

Please tell where I am wrong.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input you read contains a newline, so you have to sanitize it before you do the check, i.e.

```
if(is_dir(rtrim($response))){
```